# Avoiding DefaultCredentialsError when using google bigquery API

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-bigquery

I'm trying to execute an SQL query on some bigquery table. I keep getting a `DefaultCredentialsError` when trying to instantiate a bigquery client object. For example by doing this:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('service_account_key.json')
```

Or by doing this:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
key = open('service_account_key.json', 'rb').read()

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials(
    'my_email',
    key,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')

client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials)
```

Could there be a problem with my .json credentals file? I created a service account key:

[image: google api]

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using the (recommended) `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` way of authenticating? See here: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/google-cloud-auth.html#overview. Can you test if that works.

Comment: You're possibly hitting this bug - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/1883

Comment: Thanks @GrahamPolley. By exporting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS location I was able to instantiate the client using `from_service_account_json`. It's unusual that I would have to do this considering I am passing the location directly to the `from_service_account_json` function

Comment: That's good news @AlexG. I'll post an answer now in case others hit the same problem you did. In the meantime, maybe you want to raise an issue here -> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues and bearing in mind it might be due to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/1883

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely hitting a [bug](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/1883) with using the `from_service_account_json` method.

Instead, try using the recommended way of authenticating by exporting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable as decribed [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html).

Comment: Dead link. Now can be read about [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html)

Comment: Updated the link. Thank you.